# BIND - DNS Reverse zone : No current Owner

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7, bind

I'm doing a internal test (Centos 7 Virtual) about how to setup a DNS server.

Using bind i had no problem to get a named-checkzone -D with an OK syntax at the end.

but when i'll try to get the reverse zone , it keep giving me the no owner / no current owner name

```
[root@CentOS named]# cat db.climent.cat 
$TTL 1H 
@ IN SOA servidor hostmaster ( 
 2004070101 ;; serial 
 8H ;; refresh for slaves 
 3H ;; retry 
 4W ;; expire time at slaves 
 1H ;; negative TTL
 )  
  IN NS servidor 
 IN MX 10 servidor 
 a01 IN A 192.168.56.1 
 a02 IN A 192.168.56.2 
 a03 IN A 192.168.56.3 
 a04 IN A 192.168.56.4 
 a05 IN A 192.168.56.5 
 a06 IN A 192.168.56.6 
 a07 IN A 192.168.56.7 
 a08 IN A 192.168.56.8 
 a09 IN A 192.168.56.9 
 a10 IN A 192.168.56.10 
 a11 IN A 192.168.56.11 
 a12 IN A 192.168.56.12 
 a13 IN A 192.168.56.13 
 a14 IN A 192.168.56.14 
 a15 IN A 192.168.56.15 
 a16 IN A 192.168.56.16
 a17 IN A 192.168.56.17 
 a18 IN A 192.168.56.18 
 a19 IN A 192.168.56.19 
 a20 IN A 192.168.56.20 
 #a21 IN A 192.168.56.21 
 a22 IN A 192.168.56.22 
 a23 IN A 192.168.56.23 
 a24 IN A 192.168.56.24 
 a25 IN A 192.168.56.25 
 a26 IN A 192.168.56.26
 a27 IN A 192.168.56.27 
 a28 IN A 192.168.56.28 
 a29 IN A 192.168.56.29 
 a30 IN A 192.168.56.30 
 a31 IN A 192.168.56.31 
 a32 IN A 192.168.56.32 
 a33 IN A 192.168.56.33 
 a34 IN A 192.168.56.34 
 a35 IN A 192.168.56.35 
 servidor IN A 192.168.56.21 
 ;Els servidors de noms i de correu electrònic han de ser host A 
 correu IN CNAME servidor 
dns IN CNAME servidor 
;; Defineix dominis de serveis amb CNAMEs. IMPORTANT: es posen noms de                 màquina que resolgui DNS i no IPs. 
www IN CNAME a01 
ftp IN CNAME a02
```

and the reverse zone file

```
[root@CentOS named]# cat db.56.168.192 
$TTL 1H 
 @ IN SOA servidor.climent.cat. hostmaster.climent.cat. ( 
  1; Serial 
  604800; Refresh 
  86400; Retry 
 2419200; Expire 
  604800 ); Negative Cache TTL 

  IN NS servidor.climent.cat.
1 IN PTR a1.climent.cat. 
2 IN PTR a2.climent.cat. 
3 IN PTR a3.climent.cat.
4 IN PTR a4.climent.cat.
5 IN PTR a5.climent.cat.
6 IN PTR a6.climent.cat.
7 IN PTR a7.climent.cat. 
8 IN PTR a8.climent.cat. 
9 IN PTR a9.climent.cat.
10 IN PTR a10.climent.cat.
11 IN PTR a11.climent.cat.
12 IN PTR a12.climent.cat.
13 IN PTR a13.climent.cat.
14 IN PTR a14.climent.cat.
15 IN PTR a15.climent.cat.
16 IN PTR a16.climent.cat.
17 IN PTR a17.climent.cat.
18 IN PTR a18.climent.cat.
19 IN PTR a19.climent.cat.
20 IN PTR a20.climent.cat.
#21 IN PTR a21.climent.cat.
22 IN PTR a22.climent.cat.
23 IN PTR a23.climent.cat.
24 IN PTR a24.climent.cat.
25 IN PTR a25.climent.cat.
26 IN PTR a26.climent.cat.
27 IN PTR a27.climent.cat.
28 IN PTR a28.climent.cat.
29 IN PTR a29.climent.cat.
30 IN PTR a30.climent.cat.
31 IN PTR a31.climent.cat.
32 IN PTR a32.climent.cat.
33 IN PTR a33.climent.cat.
34 IN PTR a34.climent.cat.
35 IN PTR a35.climent.cat.
36 IN PTR servidor.climent.cat.
```

The error it gives is...

```
[root@CentOS named]# named-checkzone -D 56.168.192.in-addr.arpa db.56.168.192
db.56.168.192:2: no current owner name
db.56.168.192:9: no current owner name
zone 56.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file db.56.168.192     failed: no owner
zone 56.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

any idea suggestion or help? was looking couple tutorial or info online but couldnt manage to do the trick

PS: Happens that the Centos I'm using to do the tests before jumping in into bigger things with DNS's is in the ip 21 thats why it is commented

Answer (score 3):

Leading whitespace issue at SOA line?

Comment: There is indeed an extra space there.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on the very brief answer by hargut, the problem seems to boil down to some misunderstandings of the master file format (the standardized text-based representation of DNS zone data that your zone file is supposed to adhere to).

The error that you ask about appears to be due the the presumably accidental leading whitespace on the `SOA` line. (Same kind of problem with accidental leading whitespace appears to exist in both the `db.climent.cat` and the `db.56.168.192` files included in the question.)

The reason why the leading whitespace is critical is that the master file format is based on a set of fields separated by whitespace, with the first field starting to the very left at each line.

This left-most field is the *owner name* (referenced in the error message) and the field in itself is always present (while some other fields are optional).
In your case, with the leading whitespace, all your fields have been shifted to the right while the value in *owner name* is empty (the value before the first set of whitespace is the empty string).

An empty value for *owner name* is defined to mean that [the previous owner name should be re-used for this record as well](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-34), but that obviously cannot work for the very first record as there is no previous record.

Another thing to note is that you say that the `#21` record is commented out. It is actually not commented out as `#` is not the comment character in the master file format. If you want to comment something out you have to use [the comment character `;`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-35), like what you did with eg `; Serial`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing similar (on Debian) but I'm seeing a difference in our reverse zone files. Mine has an `$ORIGIN`.

Also, did you add the zone to `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` or similar to be brought in?

Finally comments in zone files are semi-colons `;` not pound signs `#`

From `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` :

```
zone "97.99.10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  notify no;
  file "/etc/bind/db.10.99.97";
};
```

And the `/etc/bind/db.10.99.97` :

```
user@darkstar:~/ $ cat /etc/bind/db.10.99.97
$TTL 3D       ; default ttl for records without a specified lifetime
$ORIGIN 97.99.10.in-addr.arpa.
@                      IN   SOA ns.restricted.test. root.restricted.test. (
            1536033696   ;  serial number
            1638        ;  ns refresh
            204         ;  ns retry
                10485      ;  authority expiry
                256        );  min (RFC2308 §4)

; we dont use a hostname when we tell about our nameserver(s)
    IN  NS  ns.restricted.test.
; hostname in this case is the last quad of the IP address
2       IN  PTR gw.restricted.test.
2       IN  PTR ns.restricted.test.
```

Comment: The critical difference would appear to be " @ IN SOA" vs "@ IN SOA".